# Google Sheets multiply by percent

Tags: google-sheets

This seems like it should be simple but I have no idea what's going on.

I have tried MULTIPLY, PRODUCT and =B45*(1 * 0.1)

All I'm trying to do is multiply a static number by 10%.

Cell B38 is =B45*(1 * 0.1)
Cell B54 is a static number, 7800

For some reason I am getting 78000% in B38.

[image: google sheets]

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You are nearly there.  Just format cell **B38** as a *Number* rather than a *Percent*.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Any of the following will work for you.

```
=P1*(1 * 0.1)
```

OR

```
=P2*10%
```

OR

```
=P3*0.1
```

[image]